# Multinomial Coefficients Dice Problem

Tags: probability

If 7 balanced dice, are rolled, what is the probability that each of the 6 different numbers will appear at least once?

My attempt:

$p=\frac{7!}{2!6^6}$

So if 6 different numbers need to appear, then 1 number has to appear twice. Does my answer look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 7 dice (presumably 6-sided dice) are rolled, and each number appears at least once, that implies that there are five numbers that are rolled exactly once and one number that is rolled exactly twice.

pick which number appears twice: $6$

successively pick which locations are occupied by the nonrepeating numbers smallest to largest: $7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$

Thus, there are $6\cdot \frac{7!}{2!}$ different dice rolls satisfying the conditions we are interested in.

There are $6^7$ different possible ways of rolling the dice however.

For a probability of $\frac{7!}{2!6^6}$

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need another factor of $6$ because you have $6$ choices for the number that appears twice.

Comment: Now I would say that your edited answer looks correct.  (My answer was based on the original post.)